# text formatting for article

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

For a project in laravel I have to make articles and I wanted to know if it was possible to do formatting on text (bold text, change the font, size, color) and stored in a database?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like Portable Text?
https://www.sanity.io/docs/presenting-block-text

Answer (score 0):

You can save HTML output of your [wysiwyg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor (ckeditor etc) to database or you can save your article as markdown and render it. So there are a few ways to do that.